# How do I convert a string to a double with a set amount of precision?

Tags: c++

I am parsing a file and trying to take a value I've stored in a string using stringstream and convert it to a double while keeping all the numbers in that string the same.

I have tried setting the precision of the stringstream to 12, I've also tried setting it to fixed. However, when I try to convert it using atof() or stod() it will only keep 6 values EX: 12.2343. When I need it to keep 9+ values.

Here is the code I have currently.

```
while (!inFile.eof())
{
string latData; // hold the data from the string stream
string lonData; // hold the data from the string stream
string altData; // hold the data from the string stream
string yawData; // hold the data from the string stream
string trashCollect; // hold the trash info we dont need 
double latTemp = 0; // hold the temp value to be stored in array    double lonTemp = 0; // hold the temp value to be stored in array
double altTemp = 0; // hold the temp value to be stored in array 
double yawTemp = 0; // hold the temp value to be stored in array
int count2 = 0; //count through the trash data

stringstream stringManager(line); //manage the line

getline(stringManager, latData, ','); //store the latitude
cout << latData << endl;
system("pause");
latTemp = stod(latData); // covert to a double
cout << latTemp << endl;
system("pause");
```

I'm expecting an output from the latTemp value to be the same as the latData value. For example, if latData is 12.5432345 I expect letTemp to be the same. However, after converting the string to a double using stod() I get 12.5432.

Comment: _"However, after converting the string to a double using stod() I get 12.5432."_ That's just a matter of how your `double` value is represented at output. Note the default output precision is 6, but you need to set that to 10 to see the full number. Also you should narrow your code example to exactly what's needed to reproduce your problem. There's load of completely irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from a string to a double using `stod()` happens with full precision, although the string gets truncated when you print it out. Calling `setprecision` doesn't do anything unless you pass the result to the stream whose precision you want to update.

Do:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << latTemp;
```

To print it with the `9` digits of precision

Comment: I guess I'm confused? I am trying to convert the string value into a double and then take that double and store in an array. However, when I do the conversion it only stores the first 6 numbers in the variable,

Comment: It stores everything. You’re getting less digits because it prints out less digits by default